# How to provide sharding_key to clickhouse (ClickhouseWriterError)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, clickhouse, sentry

I am setting up sentry on Kubernetes with clickhouse distributed table. All component of the deployment seem to be working except  `sentry-snuba-outcomes-consumer` which is throwing exception

`snuba.clickhouse.errors.ClickhouseWriterError: Method write is not supported by storage Distributed with more than one shard and no sharding key provided (version 21.8.13.6 (official build))`

I don't know I have looked around the config and docs but does not seem to understand how to provide the sharding key. I am completely new to Clickhouse and the Snuba.

This is my current clickhouse config

```
  config.xml: |-
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <yandex>
        <path>/var/lib/clickhouse/</path>
        <tmp_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/tmp/</tmp_path>
        <user_files_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/</user_files_path>
        <format_schema_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/format_schemas/</format_schema_path>

        <include_from>/etc/clickhouse-server/metrica.d/metrica.xml</include_from>

        <users_config>users.xml</users_config>

        <display_name>sentry-clickhouse</display_name>
        <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
        <http_port>8123</http_port>
        <tcp_port>9000</tcp_port>
        <interserver_http_port>9009</interserver_http_port>
        <max_connections>4096</max_connections>
        <keep_alive_timeout>3</keep_alive_timeout>
        <max_concurrent_queries>100</max_concurrent_queries>
        <uncompressed_cache_size>8589934592</uncompressed_cache_size>
        <mark_cache_size>5368709120</mark_cache_size>
        <timezone>UTC</timezone>
        <umask>022</umask>
        <mlock_executable>false</mlock_executable>
        <remote_servers>
            <sentry-clickhouse>
                <shard>
                    <replica>
                        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                        <host>sentry-clickhouse-0.sentry-clickhouse-headless.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local</host>
                        <port>9000</port>
                        <user>...</user>
                        <compression>true</compression>
                    </replica>
                </shard>
                <shard>
                    <replica>
                        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                        <host>sentry-clickhouse-1.sentry-clickhouse-headless.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local</host>
                        <port>9000</port>
                        <user>...</user>
                        <compression>true</compression>
                    </replica>
                </shard>
                <shard>
                    <replica>
                        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                        <host>sentry-clickhouse-2.sentry-clickhouse-headless.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local</host>
                        <port>9000</port>
                        <user>...</user>
                        <compression>true</compression>
                    </replica>
                </shard>
            </sentry-clickhouse>
        </remote_servers>
        <zookeeper incl="zookeeper-servers" optional="true" />
        <macros incl="macros" optional="true" />
        <builtin_dictionaries_reload_interval>3600</builtin_dictionaries_reload_interval>
        <max_session_timeout>3600</max_session_timeout>
        <default_session_timeout>60</default_session_timeout>
        <disable_internal_dns_cache>1</disable_internal_dns_cache>

        <query_log>
            <database>system</database>
            <table>query_log</table>
            <partition_by>toYYYYMM(event_date)</partition_by>
            <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
        </query_log>

        <query_thread_log>
            <database>system</database>
            <table>query_thread_log</table>
            <partition_by>toYYYYMM(event_date)</partition_by>
            <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
        </query_thread_log>

        <distributed_ddl>
            <path>/clickhouse/task_queue/ddl</path>
        </distributed_ddl>
        <logger>
            <level>trace</level>
            <log>/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log</log>
            <errorlog>/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log</errorlog>
            <size>1000M</size>
            <count>10</count>
        </logger>
    </yandex>
```

This is the settings for Snuba

```
import os

from snuba.settings import *

env = os.environ.get

DEBUG = env("DEBUG", "0").lower() in ("1", "true")

# Clickhouse Options
SENTRY_DISTRIBUTED_CLICKHOUSE_TABLES = True
CLUSTERS = [
  {
    "host": env("CLICKHOUSE_HOST", "sentry-clickhouse"),
    "port": int(9000),
    "user":  env("CLICKHOUSE_USER", "..."),
    "password": env("CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD", "..."),
    "database": env("CLICKHOUSE_DATABASE", "..."),
    "http_port": 8123,
    "storage_sets": {
        "cdc",
        "discover",
        "events",
        "events_ro",
        "metrics",
        "migrations",
        "outcomes",
        "querylog",
        "sessions",
        "transactions",
        "profiles",
        "functions",
        "replays",
        "generic_metrics_sets",
        "generic_metrics_distributions",
        "search_issues",
        "generic_metrics_counters",
        "spans",
        "group_attributes",
    },
    "single_node": False,
    "cluster_name": "sentry-clickhouse",
    "distributed_cluster_name": "sentry-clickhouse",
    "sharding_key": "cdc",
  },
]
```

Please can someone help me understand how to specify the sharding_key?

I inserted the `"sharding_key": "cdc",` and `SENTRY_DISTRIBUTED_CLICKHOUSE_TABLES = True` as shown above just to see if it solve the problem, but the error persist. Clickhouse and Snuba documentation does not seem to be very clear how to specify the sharing_key in configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same - Take a look at this: https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/issues/1042

You will need to

- switch off the snuba metrics consumers (set replica to 0)
- open the clickhouse replicaset and on EACH pod, you will need to update the metrics_raw_v2 table.

I used this:

```
clickhouse-client --host 127.0.0.1
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE metrics_raw_v2_dist AS metrics_raw_v2_local ENGINE = Distributed('sentry-clickhouse', default, metrics_raw_v2_local, timeseries_id);
```

After that - restart the metrics consumer and you should see all the data flowing in.